# Counting sort, index 0 of the sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I got a question about the counting sort algorithm. I was reading about it and analized it's code step by step in an example, but I don't think that I understand one little detail.. If I understand correctly, in order for the algorithm to work, you should not use Index 0 of the Sorted array at all or it's just this implementation of the algorithm, that doesn't use it?

Here is the following example of the implementation:

```
/*Lets say that we have the following array initialized,
  k is the maximum value and n is the length of the array*/
int A[] = {4,5,1,3,7};
    k = 7;
    n = 5;

void Counting_sort(int A[], int k, int n)
{   
    /*C is the count array and B is the sorted array*/
    int i, j;
    int B[n], C[k+1];
    for(i = 0; i <=  k; i++)
        C[i] = 0;

    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        C[ A[j] ] = C[ A[j] ] + 1;

    for(i = 1; i < k+1; i++)
        C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1];

    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        B[ C [ A [j] ] ] = A[j];
        C[ A[j] ] = C[ A[j]] - 1;
    }
    //so in this loop I must always traverse from 1 to <= n and leave the Index 0?
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cout << B[i] << endl;
}
```

So I'm just asking if this is a good example to look at and in order for Counting sort to work, the sorted array will always be with the size of the original array + 1 and the Index 0 will not be modified?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your implementation; namely, you initialize B to size n, but then address B[n].

Anyhow, if you want to start at index 0 within B, then you need to change:

B[ C [ A [j] ] ] = A[j];

to

B[ C [ A [j] ] - 1 ] = A[j];

and your subsequent for loop to

for (i = 1; i < n; i++)

The reason that you're starting at index 1 within B is that you place the smallest element at index equal to the count of the remaining number of that element to place - that is, the last of the smallest elements is placed at index 1.